# Unable to pass and read value of built-in variable in reusable workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow that calls a reusable workflow like below:

```
name: newCICD

on:

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  DEBUG:

    runs-on: 'self-hosted-runner'

    steps: 

      - name: Print variables

        run: |

          echo "PRINT1: -DwebRoot=${{ github.workspace }}/web-new/src/java" 

  

  BUILD:
    uses: mybank/DevOps/.github/workflows/build.yml@newfeature

    with:

      overridekeyvalue: "-DwebRoot=${{ github.workspace }}/web-new/src/java"

    secrets: inherit
```

Here is my called reusable workflow:

```yaml
on:

  workflow_call:

    inputs:

      overridekeyvalue:

      required: false

      type: string

      default: ''

jobs:

  set-global-runner:

    runs-on: ' self-hosted-runner '

    steps:

      - name: Runner details

        run: |

          echo "PRINT2: ${{ inputs.overridekeyvalue }}"
```

Output:

```
"PRINT1: -DarswebRoot=D:\Git-Runners\MYHOST\_work\web-new\web-new/web-new/src/java"
"PRINT2:  -DwebRoot=/web-new/src/java"
```

As you can see I was expecting the value of `${{ github.workspace }}` to be reflected in `Print2:`  but for some reason it is not interpreted.

How can I pass and print entire value `-DarswebRoot=D:\Git-Runners\MYHOST\_work\web-new\web-new/web-new/src/java` in reusable workflow `build.yml`?

Comment: Looks like when you're referencing a workflow using `job.uses:` it's not part of the current workspace

Comment: @bryanbcook true but then how can I pass the workspace value to the called work flow?

Comment: @bryanbcook i am able to pass workspace by setting it in the `myws` variable as `outputs` of job `DEBUG` and passing it in job `BUILD` as `${{ needs.DEBUG.outputs.myws` }} but is there an easier more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the workspace path as an environment variable in the `BUILD` job, which can then be accessed in the reusable workflow.

```yaml
name: newCICD

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  DEBUG:
    runs-on: 'self-hosted-runner'
    steps:
      - name: Check and create directory
        run: |
          DIR="${{ github.workspace }}/web-new/src/java"
          if [[ ! -d "$DIR" ]]; then
            mkdir -p "$DIR"
          fi
      - name: Print variables
        run: echo "PRINT1: -DwebRoot=${{ github.workspace }}/web-new/src/java"

  BUILD:
    needs: DEBUG
    runs-on: 'self-hosted-runner'
    uses: mybank/DevOps/.github/workflows/build.yml@newfeature
    with:
      overridekeyvalue: "-DwebRoot=${{ github.workspace }}/web-new/src/java"
    secrets: inherit
```

In your reusable workflow `build.yml`, you can then access this environment variable:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      overridekeyvalue:
        required: false
        type: string
        default: ''

jobs:
  set-global-runner:
    runs-on: 'self-hosted-runner'
    steps:
      - name: Check and create directory
        run: |
          WORKSPACE_OVERRIDE=${{ inputs.overridekeyvalue }}
          if [ -z "$WORKSPACE_OVERRIDE" ]; then
            WORKSPACE_OVERRIDE=${{ github.workspace }}
          fi
          DIR="$WORKSPACE_OVERRIDE/web-new/src/java"
          if [[ ! -d "$DIR" ]]; then
            mkdir -p "$DIR"
          fi
      - name: Runner details
        run: echo "PRINT2: -DwebRoot=$WORKSPACE_OVERRIDE/web-new/src/java"
```

The `overridekeyvalue` input is used to pass the workspace path from `newCICD.yml` to `build.yml`. If `overridekeyvalue` is not provided, the [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) defaults to using its own `github.workspace` value.

Comment: i m getting the error: `reusable workflows should be referenced at the top-level `jobs. *. uses' key, not with steps. You also missed to mention `secrets: inherit`

Comment: @Ashar True. I have rewritten the answer to propose an alternative approach.

Comment: i think this answer would work even if you don't specify this -> `    env:
      GITHUB_WORKSPACE_OVERRIDE: ${{ github.workspace }}`. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Ashar I agree, this snippet is not relevant to the GitLab CI/CD setup and can be omitted without affecting the functionality of the provided configuration. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This may fail if `/web-new/src/java` directory does not exist on the runner which is less likely. I accept the answer. Thank you @VonC

Comment: @Ashar True: I have edited the answer and added a "Check and create directory" step in each workflow.